# What is the English pronunciation of "nougat"?

Tags: pronunciation, french

***Nougat*** is a French word, deriving originally from the Latin *panis nucatus* - (nut bread), one of the principle centres of its manufacture being in Montélimar in Provence - presumably for the almonds, where almost every shop seems to be a confectioners selling little else but nougat.

In Britain we traditionally pronounce it NUGGAT, and many people still do so. However some give it its "correct" French pronunciation of NOO-GA.

Are both forms acceptable in Britain, and how does the rest of the English-speaking diaspora deal with the matter?

Comment: I think the first time I encountered the 'noogar' pronunciation was in the jingle for the hazelnut and nougat chocolate bar 'Topic'. It took me a long time to work out what noogaar was.

Comment: AmE here -- I've always heard it pronounced NEW-g't in both personal use and in advertising. Never heard *noogar* or *nugget*..

Comment: @JimMack Ah! A hybrid of the French and the English form. It is interesting looking at the different ways in which British and Americans deal with imported words. Americans will talk about "FILLAY steak", meaning *fillet*, which offers some recognition to the French (though not completely since the French do not pronounce the L in the same way). But the British make no concession to the French at all - we say "FILLETT steak*.

Comment: In France, the pronunciation is \nu.ɡa\, there is no "r" or "t" sound at the end... I wouldn't be surprised to hear a stranger pronuncing the "t" (as you say, "nugget")... but the "r" surprises me... Maybe it helps pronuncing the "a" sound the right way ?

Comment: We named our "new gato" Nougat on account of that plus his soft nougat like center, and pronounce it NOO git.

Comment: @Random Well the British don't pronounce the r at ends of words anyway (exception being the West Country where they speak like pirates and sound the r like the Americans do). So my r is largely irrelevant. I might more accurately have spelt it NOO-GA.

Comment: In Canadian English, *nougat* is pronounced noo-gat (flat *a*, but barely pronounced).

Comment: @Random I probably mentally added an R to the end of Noogaar because  the Scottish ears of my childhood had learned that English people (like my parents) didn't sound Rs. We learned to guess when Rs were intended, we didn't always get it right, which is why so many Scots though Dr Who battled the Darleks.

Comment: Arrrr!  That "talk like pirates" crack really shivers me timbers! Remember not all Americans over-pronounce their R's.  There are the Bostonians who drive cahs and go to bahs. :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez I could have expressed it better.The 'like pirates' was not directed at Americans. Notwithstanding your rhotic r, you do not sound like pirates. It's our West Country folk, and especially the Bristol population (of whom my daughter's man is one) who sound like pirates. (Steve is actually a thoroughly urbane civil servant working for the Department for Education - but he still sounds like a pirate!)

Comment: @WS2 - that's ok, we do sound like pirates too - especially when we sing the R's which drives our choir conductor crazy! :-)

Comment: I have never heard it pronounced "Nugget" in the UK, only "Noo Ga"

Comment: Here in the US I generally hear "NEW-get", "NEW-gat", or "NEW-gut", or somewhere in-between those.  I have occasionally heard it without the T pronounced, but only by people that are speaking weird already.

Comment: @Hot Licks: clearly you mean *NOO-gat* and not *NEW-gat*. I don't think anybody pronounces it *NYOO* /nju/  with a yod.  The Americans commenting are spelling as *NEW* because we pronounce the word *new* as *NOO* /nu/ without a yod. But this is going to confuse all the non-Americans.

Comment: @PeterShor ... just as "noogar" confuses rhotic speakers. [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) for the win! OP's BrE "nuggat" presumably is /'nʌ gət/, AmE /'nu: gət/?

Comment: @Mitch: indeed, I would say AmE is generally /'nu: gət/. At least, I hear this quite often, and that's what the dictionaries say.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCodkvce6eM.   Noo git

Comment: @PeterShor - I spelled it "new" because it's the same sound as in "New York City".

Comment: @HotLicks That's being obtuse. I pronounce the "New" in "New York City" as *nyoo* (i.e. /nju/ ). Do you pronounce it the same way, or as *noo* (/nu/), like many (most?) Americans do?

Comment: @Chappo - Yes, there are a number of different ways that the "New" in "New York" is pronounced.  Which is partly my point:  why expect "nougat" to be any different?

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, and how fascinating it is to see such variety! But for international users like myself, it's not meaningful to write "new" as a *sound*, since it gives me no guidance to how it might actually be pronounced. I'm not trying to be argumentative - just a gentle reminder that there are many {non-US, non-UK} EL&U users who benefit from more inclusive explanations.

Comment: @HotLicks: People pronounce *news* both *nooz* and *nyooz*, but I don't think I've ever heard anybody pronounce *noose* like *nyoos*. (Although it wouldn't totally surprise me, because English.)

Answer (score 5):

In Scotland, Warwickshire and London I have only ever heard it pronounced

/ˈnuːɡɑː/

So I'm unsure why you state that traditionally Brits pronounce it

/ˈnʌɡᵻt/

My assumption is that traditionally we pronounce it the original French way, but there has been some change over time.

Comment: It is possible that the difference is class based. I certainly grew up, in Scotland with northern English parents, calling it 'Nuggat'. Oh and we have a working class vocabulary.

Comment: @Spagirl It certainly will be class based. I grew up in an East Anglian home where all foreign things had an English pronunciation. Many of us stick with those pronunciations in order to avoid adopting a *petit bourgeois* mindset. Hence, unless I'm actually in France, I will call it "NUGGAT".

Comment: Agreed with this answer. I have only ever heard it pronounced /ˈnuːɡɑː/ and if someone said it /ˈnʌɡᵻt/ I would correct them. That said, I grew up in the south and now live in London, so it could be a regional thing.

Comment: Another Brit who's only heard _noo-ga_ pronunciation (growing up in West London), but it could easily be regional: I'd also only ever heard the Swiss food/drink/chocolate company _Nestlé_ pronounced _nest-lay_ until I moved to the North-West and discovered _some_ (not many) people pronounced it to rhyme with _wrestle_.

Answer (score 4):

British pirate here...  Usually I'd say '*Noo-garr*'.  If this was not being understood I'd probably say '*Noo-gat*', or finally, '*Noo-gate*'.

If I still was not being understood I'd probably buy some toffee, or a bag of almonds (that's '*A**l**-monds*'...)

For what it's worth, the OED offers two British pronunciations -

/ˈnuːɡɑː/ ,  /ˈnʌɡᵻt/

And one US

/ˈnuɡət/

Comment: Nuggat and awe-monds for me.

Comment: I tend to Dan's ear. I've only been here for 60 years; I've never noticed any pronunciation but noogar and if I did I'd need at least one double take to get over it…

Answer (score 4):

In the U.S., it's generally pronounced NOO-g@t, where @ is some vowel. I am fairly sure I have heard /ɪ/, /ə/, and /ɑ/, and if I believe the comments above, /æ/ is used as well.

[The](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nougat) [dictionaries](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=nougat) say /'nugət/.

And I'm sure some Americans use the French pronunciation (although these would generally be chefs, snobs, or people who know French well).

Some people might be confused by the comments above. The phonetic spelling NEW-g't does not mean /njugət/ but /nugət/. Remember that most Amercians pronounce the word *new* as /nu/.

Comment: Agreed.  (Pronounce the T, no R anywhere.) In the U.S. I have heard this only in TV advertising for a certain candy bar (many years ago).

Comment: I have the same vowel in *nougat* as I have in *nook*, so the PUT/LOOK vowel: ʊ. There may be some velar conditioning there but the existence of the minimal pair *bugger* and *booger* disproves predictable regularity.

Comment: I have never heard an American leave off the t, and I have my ears attuned to this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Having grown up in New Zealand in the 60’s, 70’s and 80s, I've only ever known it pronounced as ‘nuga’ and I’m certainly not from posh beginnings.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers. Opinions or anecdotes can occasionally be useful, but they are usually not sufficient to show that an answer is right. An answer should include explanation, context, and supporting facts. For example, you could offer peer-reviewed evidence. This is what makes answers useful – to the asker, and to future visitors. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone working in the hotel & hospitality industry in the UK is likely to pronounce it the way the French would say it - with a silent 't'. In the US, the only time I have come across this has been in a French restaurant where *nougat glacé* is a popular French "ice cream" desert. I have never encountered a non-French pronunciation of this word in the *milieu* of French restaurants in the US.

Comment: No, I wouldn't expect that, as part of a French dessert in a restaurant, that it would have anything other than a French pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

The OED gives Brit. /ˈnuːɡɑː/, /ˈnʌɡᵻt/,  U.S. /ˈnuɡət/.

I have heard and said both.

Personal experiences in the UK will definitely be subjective and class-based.